# How can I use pull request name instead of number in TeamCity branch list?

Tags: github, teamcity, pull-request

I define branch specification as "+:refs/pull/*/head" and I want to see pull subject instead of pull name.
And is it possible to make link to the github PR from main project page in the TeamCity?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect TeamCity to GitHub through the built-in connector, but I'm not sure that will give you want you want.